# How do I change the orientation/anchor point of a group?

Tags: groups

Im new to blender and I created this group and instead of rotating around the middle of the object, it rotates around some other point and the point moves when I move the object. How can I change the pivot point to the centre of the group?

[image: pivotPoint]

Comment: I am suggesting you change the word group to Blender Mesh Object in your writing above.  Group has a different meaning in Blender involving many objects.

Answer (score 1):

In edit mode .. not object mode ... move your mesh relative to the origin for an improvement.

or

in object mode use the menus in the image below.  Object/Transform

[image]

Origin to Geometry

For precise control click on part of your mesh to move the 3D Cursor then use the menu option

Origin to 3D Cursor.

Try the similar menu options.

Also I believe you are talking about a Blender Mesh Object and Not a Blender Group.